# Spread types may only be created from object types + formik

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to insert the boolean true into val1
`{...(values.val1= true)}`
It works but show the error `Spread types may only be created from object types`

I am expecting to work but without showing error

Comment: What output do you exactly want? `...` will not work for boolean. Also, `(values.val1 = true)` is an assignment but not comparation although it will also return true. Do you mean `==`? Maybe you can try `{...(values.val1 = true ? {foo: 'bar'} : {})}` to help you to understand more.

Comment: I want to assign the value in `val1`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to spread a boolean into an object. `values.val1 = true` is an assignment and the returned value of this operation is `true` (boolean). Then this expression is spread into an object. Effectively you are doing this:

```
(values.val1 = true, { ...true });
```

which is possible but doesn't do anything and TypeScript will complain.

What you might want:

```
const newValues = {
   ...values,
   val1: true,
}
```